# Truncated square wave input

Tags: plotting, functions

I'm investigating the response of some dynamic system on *Mathematica* and I want to generate a tailored square input like the one in the following picture: [image: truncated square wave]
Does anyone know how to generate such input on *Mathematica*?

Comment: Take a look at `Piecewise[ ]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another approach; However you do not have to worry about truncating the signal, just scale it.

```
Plot[WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], x/4], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1.5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
tsw[n_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{1, n <= 2}, {-1, 2 <= n <= 4}}]
Plot[tsw[n], {n, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `Boole` to truncate `SquareWave`:

```
Plot[SquareWave[x/4] Boole[0 <= x <= 4], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Piecewise[{{SquareWave[x/4], 0 <= x <= 4}}]` instead of `SquareWave[x/4] Boole[0 <= x <= 4]` gives the same result.